# How to clear cache and data in an Expo React Native App?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, caching, expo

When I use my installed Expo RN application on Android, the "Data" and "Cache" in "Settings" are always rising. I normally don't store data, so I don't understand why "Data" is rising. I would like to know how to clear data and cache programmatically

Comment: What have you tried so far and what were the results?

Comment: @ZachValenta I am using fetch and some random images from Internet. I understand why app is caching, but it's just too much. "Data" rising to 30mb in 30 mins

Comment: @ZachValenta I tried AsyncStorage.clear() and it doesn't work